# the meaning of "with none to sell"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> He captures snowflakes, tadpoles, hibernating frogs; he coaxes bread
>   from bakers **with none to sell**; he regularly appears in the kitchen
>   with fresh milk for the babies. He makes things too: paper boxes,
>   crude biplanes, toy boats with working rudders.

-All the Light We Cannot See by Anthony Doerr-

What does the bold phrase mean? Without anything to pay for?

Comment: I assume this means that he tries to persuade bakers to give some bread, but they themselves got none.

Comment: Oh I've got it! It's just an expression that he got a shrewd talent in persuasion.

Comment: Yes, anyone can buy a loaf from a baker who is selling bread, but it takes a very persuasive man to get bread from a baker who has none on the shelves. (Don't overthink it and wonder where the bread comes from; I think this is intended to by humorous hyperbole.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this means that he tries to persuade bakers to give him bread, but they themselves got none. Even though they've got no bread to sell, somehow or other he menages to get it from them anyway. Something along those lines.